# Pathfinding algorithm constrained to one-way roads

Tags: algorithm, path-finding

Say I have 5 "towns": A, B, C, D and E.

Now I want to figure out a path between these towns, but I am constrained to roads, for example A only has roads to B, C and E and B only has a road to C etc.

I can't visit a town twice and the roads are only one-way. I want to "visit" all the towns. How would I programmatically solve this?

I've already tried starting at A, then seeing what roads there are and checking each option, although all my tries so far at implementing this have failed.

Comment: What have you done so far? I did a quick google search and a few introduction popped up. Could you please add your attempts you did so far? Finally, you are mentioning three towns but to me it looks like every character represents one town and you have five characters (=5 towns).

Comment: sounds very similar to node pathing in a network

Comment: @Alex_P Sorry, there are indeed 5 towns, that was a typo. Could you link the resources you found? I couldn't really find anything myself, but that might just be my search query. As for what I've already tried, I've updated the post with that.

Comment: Did you see the links I posted? Did you find them before?

Comment: Voting to close due to lack of research. The keywords to google are "directed graphs" and "traveling salesman problem"

Comment: Another keyword would be Hamiltonian cycle